# How can I configure a Windows Embedded Standard 7 Thin Client to permanently store IE Browser Cookies?

Tags: internet-explorer, thin-client, cookies, windows-embedded

I have a Wyse C90LE7 Thin Client with Windows Embedded Standard 7.
By default it stores Internet Explorer Cookies in a Folder on the `Z:` ramdrive.

**I need the Cookies to be stored on the `C:` flash drive, so that they are persisted through reboots.**

When logged on with the `Administrator` user profile I can run regedit and see that the HKU registry hive of the `User` user profile is quite thin with no mention of a path with `Z:` in it.

What's funny is that even after I added `User` to the `Administrators` group this User seems to have only its totally restricted permissions (Only some entries and no `Run...` in the start menu, restricted control panel, etc.)

Some hints to point me to the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, our solution was to use another device, the Wyse C50LE Thin Client with Wyse Enhanced SUSE Linux Enterprise and Firefox as browser.